# Theorem 7.15 from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a problem about the following theorem:

If $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mu \bot m$ ($m$ is the Lebesgue measure), then $$ (D\mu)(x) = \infty $$

almost everywhere with respect to $\mu$, where $(D\mu)(x)$ is given by $$ \lim_{r\to 0} {\mu(B(x,r)) \over m(B(x,r))}$$

For those who do not have the book, my question is that is $\mu$ required to be regular?

For those who have the book, the proof is on p.143. My question is that if $\mu$ is not assumed to be regular, how does the following work?
$$ 
\mu(K) < 3^kN/j \text{ for all compact $K\subset W_{j,N}$ }   
\Rightarrow \mu(W_{j,N}) < 3^kN/j $$

Thanks!

Comment: Any measure on the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R^{n}$ which is finite on compact sets is regular. I think Rudin is assuming that $\mu (K) < \infty$ for any compact set $K$ though he didn't mention it explicitly in the chapter on differentiation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You get my point. Since it is not necessary that $\mu(K) < \infty$ so that Theorem 2.18 can be applied, so I am wondering if some additional condition is needed for that theorem.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Rudin assumes the condition $\mu (K) <\infty$ for $K$ compact for all positive  measures in the book. He seems to have forgotten to state this and there is no point is trying replace this condition by some other condition. Most of the arguments in the book  fail for Borel measures in the book without finiteness on compact sets. My advice to you is to treat this issue as closed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that regularity of $\mu$ is not necessary. 
Since $W_{j,N}\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ is open, there exist a countable collection of compact sets $K_i\subset W_{j,N}$ such that $W_{j,N} = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty K_i$. 
Define $A_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^nK_i$.
Then, each $A_n$ is compact, $A_1\subset A_2\subset\cdots$, and $W_{j,N} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.
By Theorem 1.19, $\mu(A_n)\to\mu(W_{j,N})$ and $\mu(W_{j,N})\le 3^kN/j$.
I did not figure out how to prove $\mu(W_{j,N})<3^kN/j$ yet but it is sufficient for the proof.